# No module named 'termcolor'

Tags: python

> No module named 'termcolor'

`pip install termcolor` returns

```
C:\Users\admin>pip install termcolor
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Not sure why I can't import this module? Here's the code.

```
from termcolor import colored
```

Comment: Do you also have installed Python3? Any new Python development should be using Python3, by the way

Comment: Do you have two versions of python?

Comment: The first step to check is print out the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable and `sys.path` python code。If it doesn't print the directory which contains the target module, then figure out why.

Answer (score 22):

My guess is that you probably have two versions of Python or downloaded the wrong module.

**1)Wrong Module:**

```
pip install term color
```

It will install a different module. To fix it, install the correct module:

```
pip install termcolor
```

**2)Two-Versions**

If you have two versions of Python, you need to specify it:

***i)Two versions of Python 3:***

If you two versions of Python3, specify:

```
pip3.x install termcolor
```

***ii)If you have Python 2 installed:***

If you have Python 2 and 3 installed, specify it, as pip works for Python2, and pip3 works for Python 3:

```
pip3 install termcolor
```

If you have only Python3, or in simple words only one version of Python, You can follow the first instruction.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way, if you already have termcolor installed to Python3.x and it still has problems when you use programs with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, is to just copy the `termcolor.py` file from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to `/usr/lib/python2.x`

Seriously, that's it. No dependencies. Just copy and go.

Comment: Good solution. works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the `virtual environment`? If you do not use virtual env, I recommend you should use it to avoid a lot of problems related to the system.

Install virtualenv for window:

**`pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`**

**`mkvirtualenv venv`**

Activating virtualenv:

**`workon venv`**

Answer (score 0):

Take termcolor.py out of `c:\python27\lib\site-packages and place in c:\python27\lib\`
might seem strange but it has a great chance to work.
In Linux, I use this command, if using windows maybe see an equivalent.

```
mv \python27\lib\site-packages\termcolor.py \python27\lib\
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this possible solution. However, it might not be a good idea to move third-party modules to the standard library folder as it doesn't scale well :/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I tried to import termcolor in jyputer notebook.

Adding the path where termcolor is installed has solved my problem:

`import sys sys.path.append("THE_PATH_To_YOUR_VERTUUAL_ENVIRENMENT/lib/python3.7/site-packages")`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `pip` solutions above but got an error:

> error: externally-managed-environment

`apt install python3-termcolor` solved it for me.